# C IPC using message queue (msgsnd: Function not implemented)

Tags: c, ipc, message

I am struggling with an issue in C. I get an error message with the text "msgsnd: Function not implemented" when running my program. Any ideas on why the code is not working? It was actually almost completely copied from a tutorial.
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 128
char buffer[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

struct mesg_buffer {
    long mesg_type;
    char mesg_text[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
} message;

void input() {
    printf("Enter Text: ");
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_STRING_SIZE);

    key_t key;
    int msgid;

    // ftok to generate unique key
    key = ftok(".", 69);

    // msgget creates a message queue
    // and returns identifier
    msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    message.mesg_type = 1;

    fgets(message.mesg_text, MAX_STRING_SIZE, stdin);

    // msgsnd to send message
    int result = msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);

    if (result == -1) {
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(0);
}

void output() {
    wait(NULL);
    key_t key;
    int msgid;

    // ftok to generate unique key
    key = ftok(".", 69);

    // msgget creates a message queue
    // and returns identifier
    msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // msgrcv to receive message
    msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0);

    printf("Entered Text: %s\n", message.mesg_text);

    // to destroy the message queue
    msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Communication test (exit with CTRL+c)\n");
    while (1) {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            input();
        }

            //the parent
        else {
            output();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program should just be able to exchange messages between both of the threads, since they share the same key. Without using "if (result == -1)" it always returns an empty string in the output function. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of machine are you trying to run this on?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was trying to run it within CLion on my Windows 10 machine and also in "ubuntu 20.04 lts", also on the same pc.

Comment: I would not expect such an issue on Ubuntu, but I'm not at all surprised to see it on Windows (with, I guess, msys2 or Cygwin to have any POSIX libraries at all).  Windows makes no claim or pretense of POSIX conformance, and compatibility libraries can only go so far.

Comment: You should check the result of msgget too. It will return -1 on failure, and you have not checked for that.

Comment: Thirdly, according to ftok’s manpage, the first string it must refer to an existing accessible file.  “.” does not refer to a file.n  Check it’s error result too.

Comment: @Max, "file" in this sense should be understood to be inclusive of directories, and "." does (generally) refer to an existing and accessible directory.  In practice, `ftok(".", 69)` succeeds for me.

Comment: Fair; the man page is unclear as to whether it means ‘file’ as in an plain file, or any filesystem object.  The second part of checking results (even in a debugger) does apply here still.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is the rest of the code working for you aswell? i can't seem to find any fixes for that

Comment: "Function not implemented" means your version of Linux doesn't have msgsnd. Not surprising because it's obsolete and they probably turned it off a long time ago. If you're on Windows, it's even less surprising. If you compile your own Linux kernel I think it's possible to enable it, but compiling your own kernel has the risk of breaking your PC so don't bother unless you are very confident. Is there a specific reason you need to use msgsnd?

Comment: @user253751, `msgsnd()` is *old*, but not obsolete.  At least, [POSIX does not say so](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgsnd.html).

Comment: @Tiiill, as a matter of fact, yes, your program does seem to work for me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what are you running this on?

Comment: I'm running it on CentOS Stream 8, w/ Linux kernel 4.18.0.